# Are SOA based apps/websites fast, how to improve performance and speed

Tags: java, android, performance, web-applications, soa

Currently I have a Java based website which have integration with DB natively using JDBC. But now I have developed an android app and a iOS app which offering same website functionality in native apps. And both android and iOS app are presently connected with website project to access APIs

What I am thinking now is to create a separate project in Java which would offer only API interface to website, android app and iOS app and in future if anything also comes which requires integration with either same business logic or with DB.

But before proceeding with it, I would like to understand whether this approach is right or not. In my opinion it would hamper speed and performance of website as it needs to access data from a service using JSON data which require conversion of objects to JSON and again parsing them to render views.

Questions:

1. Is this approach right? To create a SOA like architecture where service project will offer just APIs?
2. Will it impact performance and speed
3. If yes, how to tackle this issue?
4. Are there any other option to explore to make such architecture where several apps access same business logic or data

Answer (score 0):

1. Your idea is correct. By implementing a federated service layer that exposes APIs to all consuming apps you'll achieve separation of concerns, you will decouple UI and data model and will be able to implement core logic changes without breaking any application that uses the common layer. You will also be able to easily add more consuming apps to the scenario.
2. Yes, any processing of data in the service layer will naturally impact speed and performance.
3. There are many approaches to solving performance issues and it depends on the specific issue and your budget. Some solutions that come to mind are:

   - Scaling the layer on multiple servers + Load balancing
   - Avoiding transformations of data as much as possible (by employing a common data model for example)
4. Microservices come to mind as an alternative to a common, centralized service layer. It has its own benefits and complications. You can check out [this Martin Fowler article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143526/interfaces-integration-between-products/34419341#34419341).

Hope this helps!